# Accepting WINAMP ctrl+alt key-combinations

Tags: league-of-legends, keyboard

When playing League of Legends with Winamp and TeamSpeak. LoL ignores my teamspeak keybindings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>/<kbd>p</kbd>), and thus teamspeak correctly reacts.

But my Winamp keybindings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrowup</kbd> and so on), are probably "eaten" by LoL and Winamp does not respond.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry but I can't quite understand what you are asking? Do you mean accepting?

Comment: well if i use the shortcut for Teamspeak it works. and for winamp it doesn't

Comment: Can't help you there because i just use my G15 keyboard to flip through songs. But I did make your question understandable

Comment: @Lyrion well even though it is technically not correct what you edited, i guess that is easier to understand, btw it accepts the keyboard-defined "windows-functions"

Comment: I've never heared of Inception of keys tho ;)

Comment: @Lyrion well i suppose that is due to me not being a native speaker :(

Comment: Have you tried setting the hot keys in winamp to be global?  I've been able to use winamp key bindings while I'm in LoL

Comment: LoL does some weird things with the windows keyboard input, I have my caps-lock remapped to ctrl in my registry and I can still use caps-lock as caps-lock within LoL and not as ctrl :/.

Comment: @boiledham dude in winamp they are generally set to global if you define them in settings-global shortcuts aren't they? maybe it's because i go multiple key-combinations on some functionalities...

Comment: @Vogel612 I don't have winamp right in front of me, but I vaguely remember that there's a check box that says to use as global hotkeys. Maybe it needs to be checked before you can even set the hotkeys.

Comment: I bet if you run League of Legends windowed it would alleviate this issue.

Comment: @Ender this sounds like a nice idea, i am going to test that when i am home...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why do custom global hotkeys not work in Winamp when playing LoL?**

I don't know. It didn't work for VLC either. I would suspect, that League of Legends is swallowing those keyboard commands and not letting other applications know about them (there is probably someone who can give a much more technical answer about keyboard hooks etc).

**How do I fix this?**

Well this I have an answer to! If you go to Options -> Preferences -> Global Hotkeys you will notice an "Enable default multimedia key support" (Winamp v5.623). Check this box. This will let Winamp "hear" any multimedia keys being pressed. Now while playing league of legends you can use the multimedia keys on your keyboard to change songs, volume etc.